# Creating a very simply Shipping Calculator

Tags: c#

So I have to create a simple sales calculator, I have got the GUI made so far and here is my code so far.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //To Hold The Data
        double Weight;
        double Zone;
        double WeightCost;

        //Validate the Data
        if (double.TryParse(textBox_Weight.Text, out Weight) &&
            double.TryParse(textBox_Zone.Text, out Zone))
        {

        }
```

So far at the moment I want to assume the shipping price is $5.25. For the Zones, I need the program to recognize whether or not Zone X, Y, or Z was entered, if one of those is not entered I need some sort of error message to display. 
For zone X, $14.75 is the zone cost, for Y it is $16.15 and for zone Z it is $50.95.
I also want to display the information in 3 labels, being label_WeightCost label_ZoneCost and label_TotalCost, though I don't quite know how to display the information into the labels after doing the calculations. The Calculations are quite easy, being just 
WeightCost = Weight * 5.25
ZoneCost = Zone ( This is where I need to know how to have the program recognize whether or not it is Zone X, Y or Z and it will just equal $14.75 $16.15 or $50.95 )
Then TotalCost = WeightedCost + ZoneCost

We also need to have the program display an error if a something rather then a number was displayed in the textBox's though I can do that.

For the Zones, I was thinking, could I do an if else if kind of deal?
Like

```
if
{
//I'll add doubles like double Y = 16.15;
Zone = Y
label_Zone.Text = Zone.ToString("n1");
}
```

Comment: It's very difficult to understand exactly what your problem is. You've said the calculations are quite easy, but I'm not following which part you're stuck on

Comment: Ah, sorry for not being clear on exactly what I am asking.  Basically, my first problem is having the program recognize whether or not the user has entered one of the 3 zones, being X, Y or Z. I then need the program to take whatever zone was entered, for example Zone X cost $14.75 to ship, and display it in label_ZoneCost. That is another problem, I've displayed information in Textboxes though want to display it in a label, it looks cleaner and makes the program itself look better.

Comment: I also just thought of this, using a switch to determine the zone.

Comment: If you have fixed number of serveral zone, you should use combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the user entering in the Zone information into a TextBox, you should make them select a zone or select from a ComboBox. As this will give them zones they can enter, and you can add the cost based on which ComboBox.SelectedItem is done. 
You can then display a `MessageBox.Show()` if `SelectedIndex < 0`, which means they didn't enter anything in.

After that to display the values to your label you need to just use the Label name, followed by text `label1.text = Zone;`